# How to set spatial reference and change the extent of a raster in R?

Tags: projection, raster, rgdal

I have a raster file which was created in the projection UTM33 I want to change this to WGS84 projection so it will then match my other layers (shapefiles and rasters).  I think then i will also need to change the extent of the above raster (the one which I have just changed the projection of) so that it will also match up with my other files.  How do I do both of these things in R? I know I need to use the raster and rgdal packages and I have looked through the other topics covered on here but I still can't work it out.
Thank you very much for any and all advice!

Answer (score 0):

you want to use the projectRaster function with a crs defined by WGS84

```
??raster::projectRaster
```